# how to call jquery function externally in html

Tags: php, jquery, html

When we click on an anchor tag it should call the jquery function which is in external file but i don't know how to call a click function externally.

This is my **code**:

**php**

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loc.js'">
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="locname"> 
    <ul class="loct" >
        <li >
        <a href=# class="c" >Camp
        </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**js file**

```
        $(document).ready( function() { 
            var $flag='0';
            $(".c").on("click",function(event){
                var $trigger = $(".c");
                if($trigger !== event.target && 
                     !$trigger.has(event.target).length)
                {
                    if($flag=='0')
                    {
                        $flag='1';
                        $(".co").fadeToggle("fast");
                    }
                    else if($flag=='1')
                    {
                        $flag='0';  
                        $(".co").fadeToggle("fast");
                    }
                } 
            });
        }
     }
```

**Above code is working fine now**

Comment: no error on console

Comment: i just change the <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('js/loc.js'')?>" to <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loc.js'"> and now its working

Comment: yes path only is the problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to wrap your JS code in `<script></script>` if your file's extension is `.js`

Solution: Update your JS file with the following code

```
var $flag='0';
function myFunction(event){
    var $trigger = $(".c");
    if($trigger !== event.target && 
       !$trigger.has(event.target).length)
    {
        if($flag=='0')
        {
            $flag='1';
            $(".co").fadeToggle("fast");
        }
        else if($flag=='1')
        {
            $flag='0';  
            $(".co").fadeToggle("fast");
        }
    } 
};
```

Your anchor tag should be:

```
<a href=# class="c" onclick= "myFunction(this);">Camp</a>
```

Also, since you're using jQuery, make sure you include jQuery library as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

**HTML** file

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('js/loc.js');?>">
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="locname"> 
    <ul class="loct" >
        <li >
        <a href=# class="c" onclick= "externalFunction(this);">Camp
        </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS file**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() { 
            var $flag='0';
           function externalFunction(event){
                var $trigger = $(".c");
                if($trigger !== event.target && 
                     !$trigger.has(event.target).length)
                {
                    if($flag=='0')
                    {
                        $flag='1';
                        $(".co").fadeToggle("fast");
                    }
                    else if($flag=='1')
                    {
                        $flag='0';  
                        $(".co").fadeToggle("fast");
                    }
                } 
            });
        }
     }
 <script>
```

I thing it will help you.

Comment: Are you sure wrapping JS code inside a JS file in ` <script>` tags is valid? And how is this answer different than my answer in this thread?

Comment: yes its valid and i just changed the <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('js/loc.js'')?>" to <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loc.js'"> and now its working

Comment: @JunaidAhmed : No we cannot add any html tags into `.JS` file. Maybe she is adding this script into html page..